# Amazon aws windows instance launch using script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have been working on aws console for a while and want to launch a windows ec2 instance and bootsrap on it using powershell and winrm .Can any one help me with this.i have made a ruby script which is able to launch the instance but it is not able to bootsrap into it.

Comment: I can launch instance using the ruby script reffering the site

Comment: Can you elaborate your question in detail?

What you want ? 

Create an Instance using ruby script and after that call some script on that newly created Instance ???

Answer (score 0):

Having done similar to what you are asking I can tell you it's not a very straightforward process. If you are using the AWS provided Windows AMIs then you will need to develop a userdata script to do the winrm configuration for you on instance creation. You can use a ruby script to create the Windows instance in AWS and pass userdata script as part of that creation but the userdata script itself has to be batch and/or powershell to execute inside the Windows OS.

You can reference this [script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1), the script is actually from Anisble setup but does what you are asking, for the WinRM configuration creating a new self-signed certificate and using https for the connection on the default secure port 5986. DOn't forget to open your Security Group(s) for this instance to allow TCP 5986 inbound.

Once the new AWS instance is started and userdata script has run you will be able to connect to WinRM and remote powershell sessions using "https://:3986/winrm" and authenticate using the local Windows "Administartor" user. The password is randomly generated per-instance based off the certificate you provided when requesting the creation of the instance. You can get the password by going to the EC2 console and provide the private key. Assuming you are using the aws-sdk gem in ruby you can request the password using something like this:

```
# pemPath is the file path of your PEM file
# instance is an AWS::EC2::Instance
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new
encrypted_password = ec2.client.get_password_data(:instance_id => instance.instance_id).password_data
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(pemPath))
decoded = Base64.decode64(encrypted_password)
password = private_key.private_decrypt(decoded)
```